# JSON resolve from URL and post textview

Tags: android, json, textview

how to resolve this json for Android Studio

and need each item is individually displayed in the textview

Thank you all....

url content only

```
{"s":true,"code":0,"errors":[],"c":"2.54","y":"5.8","i":"2.9","x":"0"}
```

My Someone Activity

```
public class aFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, null);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        new TransTask()
                .execute("MYURL");
        return view;
    }
    class TransTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                String line = in.readLine();
                while(line!=null){
                    Log.d("HTTP", line);
                    sb.append(line);
                    line = in.readLine();
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    Log.d("JSON", s);
    parseJSON(s);
}


private void parseJSON(String s) {
    try{
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);

        String name = jsonObject.getString("s");
        String title = jsonObject.getString("code");
        String tag = jsonObject.getString("errors");
        String info = jsonObject.getString("c");
        String info = jsonObject.getString("y");
        String inf = jsonObject.getString("i");
        String in = jsonObject.getString("x");
    }
    catch(JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

why super.onPostExecute(s);  cannot resolve method 'onPostExecute(java.lang.string)'

Answer (score 0):

You could set the values for various widgets in the 'onPostExecute' method for your AsyncTask.

Initialize a [JSONObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) with the string returned. Then use the various methods like getBoolean, getString, getDouble, etc. for the values. You can even get nested json objects or arrays using getJSONObject and getJSONArray methods. Using JSONObject will require you to handle a JSONException in your code.

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringObject);
    boolean s = jsonObject.getBoolean("s");
    int code = jsonObject.getInt("code");
    JSONArray errors = jsonObject.getJSONArray("errors");
    //Similar to above
```

Alternately, you can also use a library like [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) to deserialize your json.

Comment: very thanks you,i update my code, i neet set post to textview1~7`,where and how?

Comment: Your onPostExecute Method seems to be outside the scope of AysncTask. Hierarchically, it should be at the same level as the doInBackground method.